# setdelayed inside manipulate originates a loop of evaluations. Why?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Why does this:

```
Manipulate[test[a_] := 2*b; test[c], {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}]
```

turns into an evaluation loop?
Shouldn't `Manipulate` only evaluate when `b` or `c` changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the `Manipulate` will re-evaluate when `b` or `c` changes, but also if `test` changes -- and `test` is being re-assigned every time any one of those values changes.  Hence the endless re-evaluation loop.

As a rule, side-effects should be avoided in the display expressions of constructs like `Manipulate` and `Dynamic` in order to avoid evaluation loops, race conditions and other surprising behaviour.  In the case at hand, I would suggest removing the implicit dependency on `b` in `test` and hoisting its definition outside of the `Manipulate`:

```
test[b_, c_] := 2*b; Manipulate[test[b, c], {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}]
```

In the real application, there may be obstacles to such a simple refactoring -- but the key point is to remove the `:=` from the dynamic expression.

Answer (score 7):

To fix the problem with minimal changes, do

```
Manipulate[
test[a_] := 2*b;
test[c], {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1},
TrackedSymbols \[Rule] {b, c}]
```

instead (i.e., add `TrackedSymbols` to tell Mathematica what to track for changes).